# How to delete cell with specific value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've made a code that adds whatever value you put in B2 in a list if cell E2 = "ADD ITEM", i'm trying to make it also delete the same value from the list with the same button action while E2 = "DELETE ITEM". I've already made the part that adds the values and it works fine but i can't progress no the deletion part.

```js
function itens() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var lista = ss.getSheetByName("BASE LAB(TBD)");

    var source = lista.getRange("B2");
    var opt = lista.getRange("F2");

    var patrimonio = source.getValue();
    var option = opt.getValue();

    var lastLineOfData = lista.getDataRange().getLastRow();

    if (option == "ADICIONAR ITEM") {
        lista.getRange(lastLineOfData + 1, 1, 1, 1).setValue(patrimonio);
        ss.toast("EQUIPAMENTO ADICIONADO");
    }
}
```

Comment: i've added the line "source.clearContent();" at the end so it clears the range where you enter the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`createTextFinder()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext) to search your chosen range for some text, then iterate through the results and use [`deleteCells()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#deletecellsshiftdimension) or [`clearContent()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) to delete the data. Using `deleteCells()` you can shift the rows so you don't have empty rows after deleting the data, while `clearContent()` will leave empty spaces if that's what you prefer.

Here's a sample:

```js
function removeItem(input) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lista = ss.getSheetByName("BASE LAB(TBD)");
  var range = lista.getRange("A:A") // the range to be searched
  var textFinder = range.createTextFinder(input)
  var results = textFinder.findAll()
  
  for (var i = results.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
      results[i].deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS)
  }
}
```

You can call this function from your current one like this:

```js
function itens() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lista = ss.getSheetByName("BASE LAB(TBD)");

  var source = lista.getRange("B2");
  var opt = lista.getRange("F2");

  var patrimonio = source.getValue();
  var option = opt.getValue();

  var lastLineOfData = lista.getDataRange().getLastRow();

  if (option == "ADICIONAR ITEM") {
    lista.getRange(lastLineOfData + 1, 1, 1, 1).setValue(patrimonio);
    ss.toast("EQUIPAMENTO ADICIONADO");
  } else if (option == "DELETE ITEM") {
    removeItem(patrimonio)
  }
}
```